# Access on $_POST variables fails on button

Tags: php, jquery

I'm keen to know how to send and manage 2 values out of one php-form without reloading/refreshing. This is a simple up-down voting formular to vote with one click.

I've startet with the form:

```
echo "<form id='votingform' method='post'>";
echo "<button id='rateup' /><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x'></i></button>";
echo "<button id='ratedown' /><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-2x'></i></button>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$id."' name='rateid' />";
echo "</form>";
```

Then I'm using some jquery to prevent formula-submit and add some visible response for testing purposes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#votingform');
  var submit = $('#rateup');  // submit button
  var submit2 = $('#ratedown');  // submit button

  // form submit event
  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

    $.ajax({
      url: '', // form action url
      type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
      dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
      data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert.fadeOut();
        submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
        form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
        submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    });
  });
});

form.on('submit2', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

        $.ajax({
          url: '', // form action url
          type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
          dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
          data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
          beforeSend: function() {
            alert.fadeOut();
            submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
          },
          success: function(data) {
            alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
            submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
          },
          error: function(e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

And added some action:

```
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){

    $vote1 = $_POST['rateup'];
    $vote2 = $_POST['ratedown'];

    echo $vote1; echo $vote2;

    // sql part goes here
  }
  return;
}
```

The $vote1 is ok, $vote2 is empty. Does anyone have a clue on this and can help me to solve this problem? Or maybe a smarter way to get this thing working? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: try making it unique?

Comment: use 2 radiobuttons and 1 button. give radiobuttons samename and just use the button for posting

Comment: Change your <button>'s to <inputs>

Comment: I doubt you will get the value of a button in the POST array - you need to use an <input type="submit" value="" /> type "button" for that.

Comment: you tagged as jquery, why? this is not full code

Comment: it is really not good practice to have two submit button in one form...instead use one simple button and one submit button and handle data with jQuery or a hidden field.

Comment: and you have `</form>";` which looks to me being set inside an echo somewhere, so no idea how to solve this, too many unknowns.

Comment: the solution is so simple, it's almost stupid.

Comment: feel free to jump in anytime

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. We're using jquery to process the form, that's why it's tagged as jquery. The version foxbeefly mentioned isn't working at all, so I think we have to use two forms instead of one. Is there no method using only one form?

Comment: well I knew that ^ - and none of the answers neither I'll bet. Why don't post your full code, instead of having everyone guessing. (wink) Can you tell what my shoesize is? There you go.... (wink).

Comment: I've updated my question and it's hopefully better than my first one!

Answer (score 1):

Button elements do not send their value - hence no POSTed value.
Change your  elements to

```
<form id='rateform' action='' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' class='votecomment' value='up' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' class='votecomment' value='down' />
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="test" />
</form>
```

Comment: are you 100% sure about that? this is not what the problem is in the question. they're using Ajax and jQuery but didn't post that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$http_post = ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

if($http_post)
{
    echo $_POST['submit']; // no result
    echo $_POST['test'];
}
```

If you click on `up` then `$_POST['submit']` will echo 'up' and if you click on `down` then `$_POST['submit']` will echo 'down'

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.